# Does there exist a retraction for these spaces?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have some qualifying exam questions using retractions that I do not know how to solve.  The only tool that I know for solving retraction problems is by using the fundamental group trick.

Here are the questions.

Does there exist a retraction from $X$ into $A$?

(a)  $X =\mathbb{R}$ and $A = [0, 1].$
(b)  $X =\mathbb{R}$ and $A = (0, 1)$.
(c)  $X$ is the Möbius band and $A$ its boundary circle.

Comment: (a), (b). Can you explicit construct retractions, and do you know that in Hausdorff spaces, what property must a retract satisfy?

Comment: (c) Calculate the map $\pi_1(A) \to \pi_1(X)$ induced from inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

(a) Just squeeze: let $f$ map $[1,\to)$ to $1$ and $(\leftarrow,0]$ to $0$ while acting as the identity map on $[0,1]$.

(b) If $f:\Bbb R\to(0,1)$ were a retraction, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac1n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=0$; what does this tell you about $f(0)$?

Answer (score 0):

Helpful fact: if $f : X \to A$ is a retraction where $X$ is Hausdorff, then $A$ is closed.